# Teradata BTEQ: disable logon prompt

Tags: teradata, bteq

When i run a teradata bteq in the CMD shell -

A little logon prompt screen pops up.

When i press enter the bteq runs.

Is there a way to disable this popup screen?

Searching the internet yields that entering a `logonprompt off` should solve the problem.

Like so:

```
.SET LOGONPROMPT OFF
.LOGON my_server

-- rest of the bteq script...

.QUIT
.LOGOFF
```

I use the following shell command to run the bteq:
`bteq < myscript.sql > log.txt`

Could you please help me get rid of the logon popup screen?

Comment: How about sending the username and password in the logon string, so that the prompt will not reappear. `.LOGON my_server/user,password`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the fully qualified logon string to get rid of the prompt.

`.LOGON my_server/user,password`

If you still want to go with only the server details in .LOGON. Along with `.SET LOGONPROMPT OFF`,  set the environment variable `GUILOGON` as `NO`.

In CMD: `setx GUILOGON NO`

**Snippet from [TD Documentation](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Basic-Teradata-Query-Reference/October-2018/BTEQ-Commands/BTEQ-Command-Descriptions/LOGONPROMPT):**

> Note that setting LOGONPROMPT to OFF is sometimes not going to be
> sufficient for suppressing all unnecessary prompts when using Windows
> BTEQ. You may also need to instruct CLI to suppress its generation of
> what is known as its GUILOGON dialog box.
>
> This can be accomplished by setting the environment variable GUILOGON
> to NO.